# Error: Could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.tools.java_version_checker.JavaVersionChecker

Tags: elasticsearch

Error: Could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.tools.java_version_checker.JavaVersionChecker
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.tools.java_version_checker.JavaVersionChecker

When i run bin/elasticsearch command on my terminal i got this error.
Don't know how to fix this issue.